# Free backlink monitoring tool

Tags: gratis, monitoring, hyperlink

I need a totally free backlink monitoring tool.

I would like to get a list of all (known) external pages that link to my site , but all I checked are payment tools.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with monitoring? Getting a list of all (known) external pages that link to pages from your site? If yes, I assume it would have to be a service that crawls the Web, correct? And you intend to use this via a Web app they offer, or do you look for a local tool (if yes, for which OS)?

Comment: "I would llike ot get a list" does not imply monitoring. For one-off cheks, you can use the Google BacklInk checker https://www.searchenginegenie.com/google-back-link-checking.html   If you **do** want to monitor, then edit your question to say "I would like to get a list  ... **and be informed when it changes**". Welcome aboard :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Moz Backlink tool](https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/) for a few free requests.

One request per week:
https://monitorbacklinks.com/seo-tools/free-backlink-checker

And there are many more with similar arrangements.  However, the sheer amount of data that needs to be processed for this type of monitoring - checking the entire internet - makes it extremely unlikely that this service will ever be available for free without these kinds of limitations.